# Postgres: Cannot connect from NodeJS (PG) with md5

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

Node v6.2 on Windows 10; PG (node-postgres) v4.4.2

Postgres 9.5 on Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty VirtualBox

I'm using the PG (node-postgres) module to connect to Postgres on Ubuntu in a virtual machine. I was able to connect using Navicat no problem, but those same credentials didn't work when I was connecting with NodeJS. The postgres log shows this:

```
xxxx@yyyy FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "xxxx"
xxxx@yyyy DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 96: "host    all             all             all        $
```

I added this line to my `pg_hba.conf` file and now it works but can anyone explain why `md5` isn't working?

```
# I added this line:
host    all             all             all                     password
# This line was already here:
host    all             all             all                     md5
```

Comment: What are your versions of Node.js and `node-postgres`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a breaking change in Node v6 so you need to upgrade "pg" (node-postgres) to v6.0.1 from v4.4.2 that you said you are using.

https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/1000